# Is there some way to save having paid Scott's Late Fees in Scott Pilgrim vs the World?

Tags: xbox-360, scott-pilgrim-vs-the-world

My boyfriend has been playing Scott Pilgrim vs the World (XBox version, if it makes a difference).

He finally saved up enough cash just now to pay off Scott's Late Fees at the video store.  He paid the fees, bought a few things from the new listing and exited the shop.  He then re-entered and the fees were back in place.

Is there any way to save having paid the $500, so when you come back you can take advantage of the cheap prices?  Or is it supposed to be a "buy as much as you can carry because you can't come back" deal?  Or is his game simply glitching in the most frustrating way possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scott's Late Fees are specific to the account+character. If you (as Scott), pay his late fees, you should have free access, as your profile (née Gamertag) and as the same character (Scott). Bear in mind it's also specific to who presses A at the counter. If you pay them, you should be able to turn around indefinitely and buy additional things. But if another player presses A, and they haven't paid the late fees yet, they will have to do so first.

If you come back as Kim, you will have to pay the late fees again.

The specific way this plays out in the menus, is:

When you enter the shop, the item list will show "Scott's Late Fee's" no matter what. If you have purchased it, go to the counter, and press A, it will change to the list of items behind that if you have already paid the late fees. And if you haven't, it doesn't, it's as simple as that.

Comment: He didn't change character - he literally walked out of the shop and walked back in :S

Comment: Did you actually go up to the counted and press B?

Comment: Aha!  It *did* save...  It's just when he walks in, they show "Late fees" even now.  If he goes to talk to the shop assistant, they show up though.  :S   I'm thinking that that is a bug...

Comment: I don't think that's a bug, personally. And go figure that I just played the game and edited that in without refreshing, so you figured it out. Whoops! Glad you figured it out. Happy new year.